# How can I list items in listbox by combobox value

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

I have two listboxes( one with data and another one is empty), and a combobox with two values( 1 and 2 ). the listbox values like "FX" where the first is the sex( Male and Female), the secont is a single letter. the cb values are the following: 1 is Male, 2 is Female. 
So the problem: If the user change the value I have to select the right items to the second combobox. For ex. if the value is 1, I have to select all the males to the 2nd cb.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var items = new ArrayList(listBox1.Items);
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    string value = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    foreach(var item in items) 
    {
        if (item.ToString().StartsWith(value))
            listBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show the code you have written so far?

Comment: you should  illustrate an  effort  to us

Comment: So: I have the following items in lb1: FA, FR, FG, MG, MD, FL, and I select the value "1" in the cb, which means I have to select all the males to the listbox2. but the SelectedValue throws nullreferenceexception.

Answer (score 0):

If you populate combobox using `combobox.Items.Add()` then use the `combobox.SelectedItem` property to get the selected item.

If you populate combobox using `DataSource`, `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties are defined use the `combobox.SelectedValue` property to get the selected item.

Or use `comboxbox.SelectedIndex` property to get/set selected item by its index.